# Why was a flag to delete an old poll declined?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, declined-flags, vote-to-delete

So, I was poking around the questions that only had [project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler) on them and found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524179/what-is-your-favorite-project-euler-question

It should be fairly clear from the title that this question is a poll... and it is:

> What was your favorite Project Euler question? Why? Did you think of a clever trick, or did you learn some new math, or did you discover a feature of a new programming language?

So I flagged it:

> Please delete this post. Its a poll from the before times. It also is rather low view and decidedly a bad question. There is no way to salvage it. It doesn't warrant an historical lock. Its better to just delete it rather than let it sit around gathering dust.

and it came back with:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

There are really only three options for what should be done with this post:

1. Flag it for 'Delete it'.  Its a low view (6813 views) poll from '09 that doesn't really fit in today's Stack Overflow.
2. Flag it for 'Lock it'.  For some reason, it should be historically locked.  I don't believe it meets the criteria, and thats why I went with the flag for delete.
3. Edit it to reopen it.  I *really* don't think this question should be reopened.
4. Raise a stink about it on meta and hope for the meta effect to delete it.

I really don't like relying on the meta effect to delete posts.  It would be much easier if the post was looked at and considered "yes, that is a poll that doesn't merit historical lock" and delete it.  Otherwise, one has to try to get the 10k users to rally behind it... and, well, various people have said that this is also a bad thing.

With such canned explanations (and I know that people have complained about canned comments to from users to users... this is no different) that don't give proper guidance to really why aren't you doing this, the only real option is to complain on meta.

So, since the flag was declined (and I'm still curious why)... 10k and above users, please delete the question.

To the mod who declined the flag: the best way to avoid this would have been to describe specifically why you can't take action on it.  I believe it could have used your intervention to avoid people attempting to invoke the wrath of meta funneled on a specific question.  Alternatively, if you believe it shouldn't be deleted, you ***and only you*** could place a historical lock on it.

Comment: That question was already closed 2.5 years ago. If you don't have the reputation to vote to delete it, then you don't have to do anything with it. You can simply leave it alone.

Comment: @BilltheLizard If you don't think it should be deleted, should it be historically locked?  Those lacking the rep to close can still flag it which puts it in the appropriate review queue.  How is this different?

Comment: I don't have to delete it or lock it. It's already closed. 10k users can vote to delete it. It doesn't require more moderator intervention, hence the declined flag.

Comment: @BilltheLizard the other option to bring this to the attention of sufficient numbers of 10k users would then be to... ask on meta?  Is there another way for someone who has less than 10k rep to bring posts that are no longer appropriate for the site and should be handled to the attention of the appropriate people?

Comment: There's a third way <10kers can help. Downvote the whole post so it reach score below 0 (or at least one that requires less 10kers to delete).

Comment: @Braiam I've [done that already](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/524179/timeline), though that still needs more... And the posts have too high a score to get kicked into the low quality review queue for awhile.

Comment: BTW, the post has been deleted

Answer (score 13):

You may or may not remember this, but a couple of years ago there was a huge brouhaha on the site because moderators were deleting old, highly-voted closed questions in response to community flags. That culminated in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity), where changes were made to the way that deletions on highly-voted questions are handled.

In general, moderators now shy away from unilaterally deleting highly voted closed questions in response to flags. As Shog9 points out in that linked question, the people flagging the question don't have their names listed under the post when it's deleted, we do.

That makes it very easy to claim that a cabal of evil moderators are deleting useful information from the site. It's a lot harder to make that same argument when posts are deleted by a number of votes from your peers. Also, moderator delete votes can only be overturned by another moderator, where community delete votes can be countered by other community members.

Letting the community act on these questions has seemed to work well, and has all but ended these arguments.

Comment: I am aware of that post and controversy. I noted in the flag that this was a low view (6800 views) post from '09.  +33 doesn't constitute 'highly voted', nor (if I am reading the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/524179/timeline) right), did it get to +20 in the first month of its existence - it took two *years* to get to +20 - the criteria mentioned in that meta post. Furthermore, it doesn't meet the [requirements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/213963) for an historical lock (stellar, high number of views). // Is there a better way to bring this to the community's attention?